# Facebook AR Studio Network Module

Tags: facebook, augmented-reality

I am working on the AR Studio recently open beta by Facebook. It's really an interesting product.

When I use the Network API documented in [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/camera-effects/reference/networking_module/networking_class), and just copy and paste the example code in AR Studio script. The response is `Error: "The domain is not whitelisted"`.

Because I could only login personal account in AR Studio (rather than a Facebook APP), so I have no idea where could I set my `whitelisted domain`.

The document is quite limited, any information will be welcome!

Comment: what does "pr" mean?

Comment: typo, product. fixed already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to "Project/Edit Properties/Capabilities". If you have the Networking module loaded, you should see Networking shown there.
If you don't see it, click the '+' sign in the lower left hand corner.
You'll see a field for the Whitelisted Domains. Add yours here.

[Where you'll add the Whitelisted Domain.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ6Q6.png)